# Load intercept url from DB in Spring Security 3.0.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm create spring 3 project that uses Spring Security.

This is part of my current context-security file:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and fullyAuthenticated"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/hello*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
```

All this url I want to load from DB(from some DAO). ie I want to check access rights for any url dynamically

How can I do this in right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using [Domain Object Security (ACLs)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html).

Or you could implement a subclass of [`AbstractSecurityInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#secure-objects).

Or you could do it in ad-hoc code; i.e. implement the access checks somewhere within your controller, and throw an [`AuthenticationException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html) if the requestor doesn't have the required rights.

All of these end up with a SpringSecurity filter catching an `AuthenticationException` on the way out and taking the appropriate action; e.g. redirecting to a login page, or return a response with "access denied" status.

Comment: I'm not sure but, I think I have to use ACLs,